# Add legend to density plot in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm using the following code in R to draw two density curves on a single graph;

```
mydata1<-read.csv(file="myfile1.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
mydata2<-read.csv(file="myfile2.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")

pdf("comparison.pdf")

plot.multi.dens <- function(s)   
{
    junk.x = NULL
    junk.y = NULL
    for(i in 1:length(s)) {
        junk.x = c(junk.x, density(s[[i]])$x)
        junk.y = c(junk.y, density(s[[i]])$y)
    }
    xr <- range(junk.x)
    yr <- range(junk.y)
    plot(density(s[[1]]), xlim = xr, ylim = yr, xlab="Usage",main = "comparison")
    for(i in 1:length(s)) {
        lines(density(s[[i]]), xlim = xr, ylim = yr, col = i)
    }
}

plot.multi.dens( list(mydata2$usage,mydata1$usage))    
dev.off()
```

Now the problem is that the graph which is being produced shows two lines but the graph doesn't include the information that which line is which. For example, in the output, it should show that the red line is "a" and the black line is "b". I'm a newbie to R which is why i'm having some difficulty. any help will be appreciated!

Comment: i got it. i add to add a legend function!

Answer (score 1):

Answer from quickR website

```
# Compare MPG distributions for cars with 
# 4,6, or 8 cylinders
library(sm)
attach(mtcars)

# create value labels 
cyl.f <- factor(cyl, levels= c(4,6,8),
    labels = c("4 cylinder", "6 cylinder", "8 cylinder")) 

# plot densities 
sm.density.compare(mpg, cyl, xlab="Miles Per Gallon")
title(main="MPG Distribution by Car Cylinders")

# add legend via mouse click
colfill<-c(2:(2+length(levels(cyl.f)))) 
legend(locator(1), levels(cyl.f), fill=colfill)
```

Comment: it gives me a "graphic device error" after i run the legend statement but after tweaking the legend statement with my code, i managed to get it right!:) thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Why did the code from quickR have to manually specify the levels and labels? this is a lot of work. in my dataset, i have more than 20 levels. When I tried to do something similar (more dynamic), my legend does not match up with the curves.